# I need to pass with data that is not visible in URL through $router.push

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I need to pass some data that is not visible in URL through `$router.push`.

Such as password, I should not show some information but pass some data.

So, I tried to use `this.$bus.$emit` and gave some data to new routers but It can not work.

like this,

*signup.vue ---------

In templates,

```
<anq-button content="next" class-prop="default" :click-handler="handleSubmit"></anq-button>
```

In methods,

```
...
this.$bus.$emit('newPayload', JSON.stringify(this.payload));

this.$router.push({
     path:`/detail?name=${this.payload.name}&userSn=${this.payload.username}`,
});
...
```

*detail.vue --------

In templates,

```
...
<anq-head header="member_info" icon-prop="info"
                  :description="`${this.payload.name}` +
         'SignUp'"></anq-head>
...
<anq-button content="check" class-prop="default"
                            :click-handler="handleSubmit"></anq-button>
...
```

In created,

```
this.$bus.$on('newPayload', val => {
                this.payload = JSON.parse(val);
                alert("eventbus: " + JSON.stringify(this.payload));
            })
```

In methods,

```
...
handleSubmit() {
                this.$bus.$emit('newPayloadForm', JSON.stringify(this.payload),
                    JSON.stringify(this.form));
                this.$router.push({
                    path:
                        `/info?name=${this.payload.name}&userSn=${this.payload.username}`
                });
...
```

I wrote the code like this. But It can not be worked in `this.payload.name`of `detail.vue`

I think it maybe is an async problem. but I don't know how should I fix this codes. Please give me help. thank you.

Comment: when you say :click-handler do you mean @click also why are you stringifying json just to parse it again. also if you are not passing in any vars you should use a computed property  not a method. Could you please explain exactly where and what is going on and what the desired effect should be. For instance what is the flow of the application. because from what it looks like your only listener is in detail.vue which does not really do anything except alert.

Comment: I want to make a Signup process. Signup process has three components :  ```signup.vue``` (/signup) -> ```detail.vue```(/detail) -> ```info.vue```(/info).  But original code have some problems, because when the first component "signup.vue" is finished, the data is registered in DB. So I should fix this code. But In ```signup.vue```, the page would bring some information such as user_id, user_password, etc. But I don't want to act with visible password in url like ```this.$router.push({path: `detail?password=${this.payload.password}`});```. so how can i hide some data when using $router.push?

Comment: So what exactly isnt working/ whats your problem

Comment: I used eveneBus but It can not bring ```this.payload``` data to ```detail.vue```

Comment: Since you are chaning views event bus wont work for this situation because when  you change the view the listenter is not yet loaded when the event is emitted you have to use a vuex store